# AWS NLB connection issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlb

I have a NLB setup on a private subnet. I am connecting to NLB using API GW via VPC Link. That works perfectly.

However when I create a lambda in the same VPC specifying the private subnet, I can not connect to the NLB using the same NLB DNS name and port that I use when connecting via API GW, I can't connect to the NLB. The  request times out.

I tried created an EC2 instance inside the VPC and specifying same subnet. I can't curl to the nlb. Times out.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are the security group rules attached to the targets of the NLB?

Comment: Inbound TCP 0.0.0.0/0 Port range covers the port I'm requesting.